# How to search for a value and find it's variable | Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In the JavaScript console of chrome, you can do

```
for(var b in window) { 
   if(window.hasOwnProperty(b)) console.log(b); 
}
```

and see all the variables in 'window'. In my case there are 50+ variables, and I want to find the one containing 1150. How would I do this? How do I search though all window.* variables?

Comment: `if(window.hasOwnProperty(b) && window[b] == 1150)`?

Comment: Note that global variables are also made properties of *window*, so there may be a lot…

Comment: @ceejayoz, If I use that, I get an undefined. I would like to have a function do that and then return the variable name that stores 1150.

Comment: I get undefined or `'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.`